# Compare bunch of numbers

Tags: java

Are any easy way in java to compare bunch of numbers ?
For example:

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
d=4;
e=1;
```

//I would like to check something like this

```
if(a<b<c<d) {  /*perform some action*/ }
if(a<b<c<d<e) { ... }
if(a==b==c==d) { ... }
```

Count of constant could be bigger

Comment: I cannot think of anything like that. Can you please clarify, how would the code look, if such a facility existed?

Answer (score 1):

You need && between each condition:

```
if(a==b && b==c && c==d) { ... }
```

Comment: I guess OP knows that, but would like a shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no built-in way to do that (without repeating variables that is) but you could make some custom methods, e.g.

```
boolean ascendingOrder(int... args) {
  for( int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++ ) {
    if( args[i] >= args[i+1] ) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if( ascendingOrder( a, b, c, d ) ) { ... }
if( ascendingOrder( a, b, c, d, e ) ) { ... }
```

The same could be done for `allEqual(...)` etc.

Especially if there are more constants this might make things more readable with the downside that you don't directly see the operators. But if you have such a situation quite often or many constants a different design might actually be better (depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

you could use like

```
if(a<b && b<c && c<d) {  /*perform some action*/ }
if(a<b && b<c && c<d && d<e) { ... }
if(a==b && b==c && c==d) { ... }
```